# .html not working fine in codeigniter in case of ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, url

I want to use .html for all pages on my website.My website is in codeigniter so I change the following line as in config.php file

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

On Pages it is working fine but in case of ajax its not working. Also in some cases I have relocated files to controller_name/value in these cases it is becoming like controller_name.html/value

How to use .html correctly and perfectly Please help because my client need in .html format.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the '.html' suffix (or any suffix at all) you should generate urls in of this type:

- controller.html
- controller/var.html
- controller/var/other.html

Give it a try, should work with Ajax.